# I cannot fill the 2d svg image

Tags: bezier-curves, blend-files, 2d, svg

I am following the youtube video below

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PeXu0Kkoaqg

In video at 2:49 he fill the image with f

I wanted fill the custom image like that way

So I converted curve to mesh and pressed f

[image: image of curve(converted to mesh before pressing f)]

[image: After pressing f]

But f did not work and alf + f did fill the face bit but did not work properly

Comment: You’re in object mode. He was in edit mode. Also, F creates edges or faces, and if the selected edges do not form a solid loop, things may get goofy.

Comment: Thank you for your commen but I also tried with edit mode(with tab) and I double checked if it creates solid loop edit: I solved the problem with selecting specific dot and pressing f